# Retrieve calendar event entry information

Tags: blackberry, calendar, blackberry-jde

I have few meeting request in my native calendar scheduled for different date and time,i am trying to read the entire events scheduled for a specific date using the folloing code.

```
private void getEvents() {
          try {

             EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
             Enumeration events = eventList.items();
              while (events.hasMoreElements()) {
               Event event = (Event)events.nextElement();

                if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.SUMMARY) && event.countValues(Event.SUMMARY) > 0) {
                    String subject = event.getString(Event.SUMMARY, 0); 
                    Dialog.alert(subject);
               }  
                }

           }
           catch (PIMException e) {
               Dialog.alert(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

I am able to get the subject from native calendar ,but i want the code to read the meetings along with date and time,I am not able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The Date/Times of events are stored in the fields Event.START and Event.END as long values containing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584050/not-able-to-read-the-time-from-native-calendar-event), and the API documents for the [Event interface](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/pim/Event.html).