# Not able to read the time from native calendar event

Tags: blackberry, calendar, blackberry-jde

I have created a appoitment for  particular date and time in Blackberry calendar,i am trying to read date and time using the following code,but its showing the error.

```
 private void getEvents() {
          try {

             EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
             Enumeration events = eventList.items();
              while (events.hasMoreElements()) {
               Event event = (Event)events.nextElement();

               if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.ALARM) && event.countValues(Event.ALARM) > 0) {
                    long alarm = event.getDate(Event.ALARM, 0); 
                    System.out.println(alarm);
               }

           }

           }
```

i am not sure what is wrong in if loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field Event.ALARM contains:

> Field specifying a relative time for an Alarm for this Event. Data for
>   this field is expressed with an INT data type. The alarm is expressed
>   in seconds and derived by subtracting the alarm value from every
>   date/time occurrence of this Event. For example, if this field has a
>   value of 600, then the alarm first occurs 600 seconds before the
>   date/time value specified by Event.START. For re-occurrences of the
>   event, the alarm is calculated by subtracting the stored value from
>   the date/time of the specific event occurrence.

So you need to get the value from the field Event.START for the Date/Time of the Event start. You can then subtract the value of Event.ALARM (as seconds) from the start Date/Time to get the time for any requested reminder.

```
long start = event.getDate(Event.START);
int alarm = event.getDate(Event.ALARM);
if (alarm > 0) {
   long reminderTime = start - (long)alarm * 1000L;
   ...
}

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
String dateString = sdf.formatLocal(start);
```

Comment: long start = event.getDate(Event.START) gives the value as 1331128800000 a long value how will get time and date out of this?

Comment: import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; is not supported in BB JDE6.0 ?Getting an error while adding this

Comment: net.rim.device.api.i18n.SimpleDateFormat